# if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is for a project in my intro to javascript class. Here are the instructions:

*An architect's fee is calculated as a percentage of the cost of a building. The fee is made up as follows:
8% of the first $5,000.00 of the cost of a building.
Add 3% of the remainder if the remainder is greater than zero but less than or equal to $80,000.00, or 2.5% of the remainder if the remainder is more than $80,000.00.*

So I have the program started with this code, but how would I go about finishing it?

```
var totalCost;
var architectFee;
var architectPay;

//prompt user to enter total cost of building
totalCost = prompt("What is the total cost of the building?");

//Output architect pay
if (totalCost <= 5000) {
  architectFee = 0.08
  architectPay = totalCost * architectFee;
  document.write("For a building that will cost $" + totalCost + "," + "the architect's pay will be $" + architectPay);
}
```

Comment: What you need is to open some JavaScript book and start learning :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: Start by checking if it's over $80k, elseif over $5k, else (it was <= 5k)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's entirely a JS problem since, given the way the cost is explained, I needed to take a second look.  To rephrase the cost structure more clearly (in the same way tax brackets are structured): IF the cost is > 85000, the fee is (275 + .025 * cost); otherwise, if the cost is > 5000, the fee is 250 + .03 * cost; otherwise, the cost is .08 * cost

Comment: Since you seems to know the operators in `if`, the rest is basically basic... basic... math.

Answer (score 0):

Cost can be calculated one way if the totalCost is equal or less than 5000, or if it is greater than 5000.  If it's less than 5000, you only need one calculation.  If it is greater than 5000, you need to take the remainder and depending on whether it is greater or less than 80000 you apply a different percentage to the remainder.  Here is a rough layout of how that would work.

```
var totalCost;
var architectFee;
var architectPay;

//prompt user to enter total cost of building
totalCost = prompt("What is the total cost of the building?");

//Output architect pay
if (totalCost <= 5000) {
  architectFee = 0.08
  architectPay = totalCost * architectFee;
  document.write("For a building that will cost $" + totalCost + "," + "the architect's pay will be $" + architectPay);
}
else{
  var architectPay = 0.08 * 5000;
  var remainder = totalCost - 5000;
  if(remainder <= 80000){
    architectPay = architectPay + (remainder * 0.03);
  }
  else if(remainder > 80000){
    architectPay = architectPay + (remainder * 0.025);
  }
  document.write("For a building that will cost $" + totalCost + "," + "the architect's pay will be $" + architectPay);
}
```